# Magento 2: Left Category Sidebar from website (copy of question)

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, category-view

I am trying to create left sidebar category navigation for my website. But it shows only default category. It does not show any other subcategories.

I activated all category `is_anchor`, and re-indexing also setup flat category. but still having the same issue any help.

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98994/categories-not-displaying-in-left-sidebar-filter-options Do u have product in that category?

Comment: Yes I have product in one category

Answer (score 0):

If you open sidebar.php, you will see, in the function `getChildCategoryView` to fetch the subcategories funtion `getSubcategories` is called. The function `getSubcategories` will return children Nodes only if you enable "Use Flat Catalog Category" in the Admin settings.

1.You have to enable "Use Flat Catalog Category"

2.Run re-indexing command. php bin/magento indexer:reindex

3.Flush Cache php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

Go to your "Default Category", "Design" tab and choose the '2 columns with left bar' Layout